# Inputting a suit as a product... option to choose different jacket and trouser size

Tags: configurable-product, catalog, bundled-product, magento-1, grouped-products

Previously we had only used Config products in Magento. However we have taken delivery of suits and I want to offer these as a jacket and a trouser (Can only buy both from the same product page). However, I want users to be able to choose their jacket size and trouser size and manage stock.

I've tried to setup via as a config product, but can't manage stock this way as the product is fixed and users can't mix and match. I've played around with 'Grouped' and 'Bundled' products but not to much success.

Comment: Currently working on this module for my own store.
I used grouped products phtml which needed a lot of extra stuff added.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use bundle products for this issue.

A suit is a bundled product. You create simple products for jackets, each with a different jacket size. Then you create simple products for trousers, with different sizes also. You add both of them to the bundle product. The user will be able to choose completely different sizes of these products and put them into the cart. I don't see why this should not work. (?)